# Checking for null or undefined VS handling errors VS returning bogus in JS

Tags: javascript, error-handling, polymorphism

similar question in Java: [Java: check for null or allow exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223730/java-check-for-null-or-allow-exception-handling)

related:[How to deep check for "null" or "undefined" with JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23335580/how-to-deep-check-for-null-or-undefined-with-js)

assuming `a.foo()` is a well-tested function that returns either

`undefined` or an object with a function such as `{bar:()=>log('baz')}`,

hence, it would seem logical to write

`a.foo().bar()`

which obviously won't work.

(the `undefined` is the result of an empty `return;` when no information can be delivered)

Should

**1. The operation be tried,**

`try{a.foo().bar();}catch(e){}`

**2. a new variable be declared**

```
const u = a.foo();
if(u) u.bar();
```

**3. or `foo()` return `{bar:()=>{}}` instead of `undefined`?**

so that

```
a.foo().bar();
```

can be written normally?

what is the industry standard? what is fastest?

Comment: It is a personal opinion on what to do, there is no right answer.

Comment: what is the industry standard? what is fastest?

Comment: There is no standard. I can tell you no one would use try catch

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, this is a personal opinion and I would also stick to it that most people would try to avoid the try-catch story...

But anyway I wanted to add that you can also simply check:

```
a.foo() && a.foo().bar()
```

in case `a.foo()` will return `undefined`, then the right side wont be executed and thus this expression return undefined.

On the other side, if `a.foo()` is not `undefined` than the right side will be executed and this expression will evaluate to the result of `a.foo().bar()`

Comment: but that is bad because you are calling the method twice. If it is expensive it is not wise. If it is just a static property, that is a way to do it.

Comment: in that case, just assign `a.foo()` to a variable and substitute `a.foo()` with the variable name. Than you call it just once as in a try-catch